# mongodb want export collections missing semicolon

Tags: mongodb

I got following error when I want to execute this command on CMD

Command

```
mongodump -d remix-expenses -o ./
```

Error:

```
SyntaxError: Missing semicolon. (1:12)

> 1 | mongodump -d remix-expenses -o ./
```

I installed it on windows and added the env variables Path. I can connect to my cluster via CMD

```
mongosh "mongodb+srv://cluster0.xxx.mongodb.net/" --apiVersion 1 --username xxx
```

So after that I enter my password and now I can play around and I am logged.

Then I want to export my mongo collections but I got missing semicolon. What I am doing wrong ?

I Found this:

```
You are probably trying to run mongoexport from inside the Mongo shell. That command must be executed outside it, from your OS command shell.
```

But when I am trying to do it outside the mongoshell only in my cmd then I get

```
The command “mongoexport” is either misspelled or
could not be found.
```

Answer (score 0):

mongoexport is now part of MongoDB tools package.You can install tools package by following below link
https://www.mongodb.com/docs/database-tools/installation/installation/